# Unable to find the vendor of my android tablet

Tags: tablet

I have salvaged an android tablet from my cousin's drawer and it has not been opened for one years, I guess. It's still running in Jelly Bean. I googled for it's vendor, but I can't find any. I could not find any config details or anything. I wanted to do some root level work on this tab.

The model number behind it is ACEPad D732. Just want to know the vendor name 
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: What does `adb shell "getprop | grep 'ro.product.*'"` give? More specifically,  `adb shell "getprop | grep -e 'brand' -e 'manufacturer'"`.

Comment: Now that I think about it, when you boot your tablet, what do you see until it boots to home screen?

Comment: @Firelord ACE...

Comment: @Firelord, it shows ACE.

Comment: Then I suppose it is the name of the brand.

Comment: @Firelord, when give this adb shell "getprop | grep -e 'brand' -e 'manufacturer'", I am getting error: device not found. Although the tablet is connected in debugger mode however, I have failed to add the USB Vendor IDs in my ubuntu.

Comment: Don't bother about the adb at the moment. You can use a terminal emulator app to execute `getprop | grep -e 'brand' -e 'manufacturer'` or simply use a file manager to go to /system. There, open build.prop in a text editor and look for the terms brand or manufacturer.